# 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' already has a dependency defined for 'System.IO.Packaging'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I use VS 2010 in 64 Bit windows 7.
When I tried to build my .Net project, error occurs:

```
Error   1   NuGet Package restore failed for project ImageExplorerServer: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' already has a dependency defined for 'System.IO.Packaging'
```

I have just install NuGet Package manager in extension manager, how to solve this problem?

Comment: _"how to solve this problem?"_ - upgrade VS (and Windows, probably)?

Comment: I could not do that, it's office computer and all other people use windows 7 and VS2010 for our projects